# Make the Community ♦︎︎︎︎︎ account able to re-delete self-deleted questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, community-user, automatic-deletion

The auto-deletion script runs at [~3AM UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273831/why-do-most-scripts-egserial-downvote-detecting-run-at-3am) | [every day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) This is too easy to circumvent. A user who wants to thwart the Roobma can delete their question manually before the auto-deletion script runs, and then they undelete it after the script runs (because the Community user cannot delete a question that's already deleted). This keeps dead, unanswered questions visible on the site when they really should be deleted. Circumventing auto-deletion is not good for the community.

This issue can be solved by allowing the Community user to delete questions that have already been deleted by the OP. This way, people won't be able to circumvent auto-deletion using the method above, as their question(s) will be auto-deleted no matter what.

Comment: How many questions get deleted then undeleted like that? I really don't think there are that many

Comment: Without evidence that this is being done regularly, I don't see a need for this.  Especially given that a mod can easily deal with a rare one-off instance of such behavior.

Comment: I don't see this being a big issue either, but good thinking (although it's possible this is already addressed by the system...)

Comment: Have you seen any actual evidence of someone abusing this feature? That would make this feature request much more concrete and harder to dismiss.

Comment: *"This keeps dead, unanswered questions visible on the site when they really should be deleted."* yeh but for how long? the auto-deletion runs *every day* so the user has to do this *every day*, at one point they'll just stop and boom, question gone. even then if the question is bad enough that the sweeper is going to get rid of it then chances are someone is going to find it and vote to delete or flag it which puts it in the mod ques and then deleted later on,without the sweeper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no reason to implement this feature (especially since it would mean taking time away from more important features). The only reason the Roomba runs is to [clean up all the unloved questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/323179). It's not some type of punishment, so it's not ban-worthy in itself.

Keep in mind that Roomba comes around [every day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/323179) at 3 AM. It's not worthwhile to be working that hard to beat the Roomba when your efforts could be spent in more effective ways. People would just repost the question instead (which is generally OK when the question was deleted automatically and it's an on-topic question).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's "generally OK". See [this (newer) meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368215).