# Roomba ate my question, but I still want an answer. What now?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

30 days ago, I asked [Undo “Install Certificates.command”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49900685/1709587)
. I thought it was a decent question, but it drew a downvote. Now [Roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=roomba) has come along and deleted it.

What are askers supposed to do when their non-closed question that they still want answered gets auto-deleted? Is it acceptable to just copy and paste the content and ask an identical question?

Screenshot of the particular question for <10k users (although I'm interested in getting advice for the general case, not just this specific one):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that it is not so much a programming issue as more of a general computing one, assuming those certificates go in a central store somewhere? Or is that way-off with Python? Not a dev in that area at all but I love to speculate / show-off my general ignorance.

Comment: related MSE post but not quite what you are asking... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa

Comment: @rene I don't know where precisely the certs go. But I presume (given that they're installed by a command inside a `/Python 3.6/` folder, and given that they *didn't* need installing for pre-3.6 versions of Python) that it's a Python-specific store, and thus that this is purely a problem about configuring Python, which makes it (IMO) an inherently programming-related and on-topic question. In any case, nobody cast a close vote on it.

Comment: It's back now...

Comment: @JonClements Well, I suppose "Ask on Meta" (or maybe also "flag for undeletion by a mod"?) is a possible solution then. I'm not sure whether it should be the general-case solution though.

Comment: I'd advise against flagging for a mod - we're not always going to be able to determine undeletion is necessary and probably won't see it for  a while. Meta is fine - you might get the rest of the necessary undelete votes or feedback you didn't get while the question was alive that may lead to getting a new question out there.

Comment: @JonClements FWIW, "the rest of the necessary undelete votes" would've been *30* in this case. That'd at least be a sight to see, if it worked! I wonder if the revision history styling would even cope with listing that many names...

Comment: How'd you work that one out? You just needed 2 more...

Comment: @JonClements There's a popup after casting an undelete vote - it told me I needed 30 more. Either that or I've gone insane.

Comment: @JonClements Likewise, where are you getting *2* from?

Comment: From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that - which I was looking for as it also kind of answers your Q here...

Comment: @JonClements FYI, I'm not insane, just picked what was, in retrospect, not the most reasonable possible interpretation of an ambiguous sentence in the UI: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6964768#6964768

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this.

- Unfortunately the quickest way, going to the SOCVR chat room, is not allowed by the room's policy if the question is yours (the room's rules prohibit making requests on your own posts, or posts you've answered). However, if the question is not yours, please feel free to bring it before SOCVR with a [undel-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undel-pls) tag (and preferably a [10k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/10k) tag, too) and the reason why; if enough users with undelete privileges determine the question is on-topic, they will likely undelete it for you.
- Alternatively, make an edit to the question to try and improve it; edits do bump deleted posts, so 10k users will be able to see the post and can visit it, possibly casting undelete votes if they deem it necessary.
- Likewise, if you have 10k+ reputation yourself, you can cast the first undelete vote, and the post will show up in the 10k tools page under the "recent undelete votes" section. Even without this, the question should show up in the 10k tools page under "recently deleted" (I'm not actually sure about this... can a mod or staff confirm whether Roomba'd questions appear here?)
- Finally, you can ask here on Meta for help. Meta is precisely the place to ask about questions you asked on the main site and why they got closed or deleted, or how you should have gone about asking a question to get a better response, as in this case.

As mentioned in the comments under your question, I would not recommend flagging the question for a moderator, because the moderator who handles the flag is not guaranteed to be familiar with the technology or the question's subject matter in order to pass unilateral judgment on it.

Comment: "edits do bump deleted posts" I don't think it shows them if the deleted post is *the* question. I don't see deleted questions on the active list in the sites I have 10k.

Comment: Deleted questions cannot be edited.

Comment: @user202729 editing deleted questions is possible for 10K users, users having less than 10K indeed can't do that, that's my experience at sites where I have different rep allowing to check that. Tyler, I see Roomba'd questions in recent deleted list in 10K tools page at the site where I have sufficient rep

Comment: @user202729 deleted questions can't be edited by the OP of the question if they self-deleted them. They have to undelete before editing.

Comment: Why don't you suggest to ask a new question, improving on the old one, adding the research the OP did in that month? This seems like the fastest way, especially for a <10k reputation user.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Where in the meta question above does the OP say they have done a month's worth of research? That is a huge assumption that would essentially mean a totally different question; I didn't suggest asking a new question because that's typically frowned upon by the system when you have the same exact question. For the same question, you should get the existing one undeleted. For a different question... it's a different question so I don't think this scenario applies.

Comment: @TylerH Well, they *should*. You don't just ask a question and let everything up to others. You should still keep trying to answer it by yourself with your own research. If after one month you did not find absolutely nothing you probably still add something you have looked up but "discarded as not useful" or tried and failed to make it work.
Anyway: given that the old question is deleted it does not really matter much if you ask a new question.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I agree that you should continue searching, but if you follow that to logical conclusion then after 30 days of initially having the problem in the real world you typically no longer have the problem because **a)** you already found the solution, **b)** got someone's help IRL or elsewhere, or **c)** someone else did it at your job or a different solution was implemented because tasks have SLAs and can't just sit waiting for an answer forever

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta And even *if* you have done lots of research, you should still preferably edit it into the existing post, because that makes a much stronger case to get it undeleted, and again, bumps the post. BTW, "the old question is deleted [so] it does not matter much] is wrong - getting the question undeleted will help remove a tick in the box for a question ban. Asking a new question after your last one got deleted will do the opposite, and may trigger a lot more checks/balances in the (far) future as SO implements wizards/question quality things.