# Tweak the "X votes remaining" popup when voting to undelete

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

If I click the "undelete" button to cast a delete vote on a post that I didn't delete, a popup appears with a message like:

> Vote to undelete this post? (29 votes remaining)

[image: Screenshot showing the popup described above]

This wording is ambiguous. The intended meaning is that *I have* 29 undelete votes left that I can cast today. However, it's open to being interpreted as meaning that the *post needs* 29 more undelete votes to be undeleted. In retrospect, maybe I'm a moron, but as somebody who rarely votes to delete or undelete things and is unfamiliar with the rules around how many votes are needed to perform either action, this [recently misled me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368215/roomba-ate-my-question-but-i-still-want-an-answer-what-now#comment591731_368215).

Can we simply change the copy to read

> Vote to undelete this post? (You have 29 votes left today.)

instead? This would eliminate the ambiguity and make the message consistent with the *"You have X votes left today"* warning when casting upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: Yup! I don't know much about delete votes, and my first thought(s) on looking at that screenshot was, *Why do they need 30 votes to undelete something?! Maybe it has too many downvotes...nope.*

Comment: You're telling me.

Comment: This is the same verbiage for delete votes and for close reopen votes IIRC, so it shouldn't really be problematic... but I do support the rephrasing, as it does make it more clear/explicit.

Comment: *This post had been delvoted by Jon Skeet; 41 more undelete votes needed...*

Comment: Are the 29 undelete votes remaining *before*, or *after*, clicking cancel?